# WSS4J and Apache Axis does not work

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, axis, wss4j

I try to use WSS4J with an Axis Web Service, but nothing happens. It seems that WSS4J is not being used at all. All necessary libraries are in WEB-INF/lib directory. The service is being deployed with org.apache.axis.client.AdminClient utility.

Here is my deploy.wsdd:

```
<deployment xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/"
xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java">

<!-- Services from AccountsServiceImplService WSDL service -->
<service name="AccountsServiceImpl" provider="java:RPC" style="wrapped"
    use="literal">
    <requestFlow>
        <handler type="java:org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllReceiver">
            <parameter name="passwordCallbackClass" value="haha" />
            <parameter name="action" value="UsernameToken" />
        </handler>
    </requestFlow>
    <parameter name="wsdlTargetNamespace" value="http://accoutsservice.abc.ru" />
    <parameter name="wsdlServiceElement" value="AccountsServiceImplService" />
    <parameter name="schemaQualified" value="http://accoutsservice.abc.ru" />
    <parameter name="wsdlServicePort" value="AccountsServiceImpl" />
    <parameter name="className"
        value="ru.abc.accoutsservice.AccountsServiceImpl" />
    <parameter name="wsdlPortType" value="AccountsServiceImpl" />
    <parameter name="typeMappingVersion" value="1.2" />
    <operation xmlns:operNS="http://accoutsservice.abc.ru"
        xmlns:retNS="http://accoutsservice.abc.ru" xmlns:rtns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        name="sendAccountNumber" qname="operNS:sendAccountNumber"
        returnQName="retNS:sendAccountNumberReturn" returnType="rtns:string"
        soapAction="">
    </operation>
    <parameter name="allowedMethods" value="sendAccountNumber" />

</service>
```

No errors happen despite I don't even have the `haha` class (see `passwordCallbackClass` parameter in deploy.wsdd). I can freely send SOAP requests without WSS headers to my service.

**UPDATE**

I have resolved some classpath issues. When I try to open `http://localhost:8080/axis/servlet/AxisServlet` page I see an error: `org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender`. WSS4J jar's are in {tomcat}\webapps\axis\WEB-INF\lib directory. What I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE #2**

Is seems that nither `wsdl4j` jar contains `org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender` class nor `wss4j` jar. However, this class *was* in `wss4j` jar for versions 1.5.x. Now it is missing. Documentation for WSS4J is outdated.

Comment: Is your service listed by the webserver at URL _http://hostname_server:your_port/axis/servlet/AxisServlet_ ? Is the service WSDL shows at URL _http://hostname_server:your_port/axis/services/YourService?wsdl_ ?

Comment: By the exception, in my opinion you have some version's problem. If you unzip the _wsdl4j_ , do you find the class? What are the version of Java, Tomcat, Axisand  other used library?

Comment: Axis 1.4 (http://axis.apache.org/axis/), WSS4J 1.6.9 (http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/), Tomcat 7.0 (http://tomcat.apache.org/)

Comment: It seems to be a version conflict, but it is not documented. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WSS-248. The idea of version conflict was yours, alepuzio, so answer the question and I'll accept it.

Comment: Hi, what was the final solution to this issue. I am having a similar issue with same error message. I am using axis 1.4, wss4j 1.5.4, and tomcat 7. The issue has only started happening since we upgraded from tomcat 6 to 7. Any help /advise would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Wss4j is more compatiable with CXF. If you are using Axis try to use Rampart instead http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/